# passing data to angular-ui modal when using controller as vm

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

i need to pass an object to modal controller , i have tried different approach , here is my final code , the object is passed but i get big error in console

```
Error: [$injector:unpr]
```

here is my code

```
vm.openAttendeesModal = function (meeting) {

                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: '/App/Main/views/meetings/AttendeesModal.cshtml',
                    controller: 'attendeeController',

                    resolve: {
                        meetingSelected: function () { return meeting }
                    }
                });
            }
```

and here is my modal controller

```
angular
      .module('App')
      .controller('attendeeController', attendeeController);

    attendeeController.$inject = ['meetingSelected', '$scope', '$modal', 'meetingService'];

    function attendeeController(meetingSelected,$scope, $modalInstance, meetingService) {
        /* jshint validthis:true */
        var vm = this;
        vm.meetingSelected = meetingSelected;
```

and here is complete error

```
angular.js:12520 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=meetingSelectedProvider%20%3C-%20meetingSelected%20%3C-%20attendeeController
    at Error (native)
```

the funny part is everything is working , even i have access to passed object , but i just feel something is wrong because of that fat error.

any suggestion ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: '/App/Main/views/meetings/AttendeesModal.cshtml',
                controller: 'attendeeController as ctrl',

                resolve: {
                    meetingSelected: function () { return meeting }
                }
            });
```

or add `controllerAs: "ctrl"`

**Edit:**

if you add `"attendeeController as ctrl"` in  `AttendeesModal.cshtml` remove it.

Comment: you're welcom.i was glad to help you :)

Comment: if you add "attendeeController as ctrl" in  AttendeesModal.cshtml remove it. this is very important line .